# htaccess redirect starting URL expression to blog page

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to redirect certain URLs starting with an expression. For ex

I want to redirect:

`www.example.com/%2FE` (`www.example.com/%2FExxxxxxxx`) to my blog page in my `.htaccess` file.

I can redirect `www.example.com/2FExxxxx` but I am not able to target the `%`.

*The `xxxx`... I have used in the URL is to represent any expression after `%2FE`.*

This is my code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule %2FE /blog [R=301,L]
<IfModule>
```

Can anyone here help me?

Comment: `%2F` is the percent encoded notation of `/`. So the actual URL you are trying to rewrite is something like `https://www.example.com//Exxxxxxxx`. Such URLs only make sense if their path component is not used as such, but evaluated on application level. So inside php for example. Where decoding such a string is valid and sense making.

Comment: So does it mean there is no other way to sort it via htaccess?

Comment: You don't have to, actually. Doubled slashes are ignored anyway by the http server. So `https://www.example.com//Exxxxxxxx` produces exactly the same result as `https://www.example.com/Exxxxxxxx`.

Comment: @arkascha The encoded slash (`%2F`) in the URL-path will (by default) cause Apache to reject the request with a 404. It's not decoded unless `AllowEncodedSlashes On` is set in the server config. (See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74946542/369434)) below)

Comment: @MrWhite That is interesting, thanks. I am surprised by that, I never met an http server that actually rejected such a request and I tried again yesterdays to be sure. I did not know that depends on a setting. So thanks for the information!

Answer (score 2):

By default Apache rejects (with a server generated 404) any URL that contains an encoded slash (`%2F`) in the URL-path part of the URL. This occurs before the request is processed by `.htaccess`. (This is considered a security feature.)

To specifically permit encoded slashes, there is the [`AllowEncodedSlashes`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowencodedslashes) directive (default value is `Off`). But this can only be set in a *server* or *virtualhost* context. It cannot be set in `.htaccess`. To permit encoded slashes, `AllowEncodedSlashes` can be set to either `On` or `NoDecode` (preferable).

For example:

```
# In a server / virtualhost context (not .htaccess)
AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode
```

Then, once the above has been implemented in the server config and the webserver restarted, you can proceed to match the slash using mod_rewrite in `.htaccess`...

> ```
> RewriteRule %2FE /blog [R=301,L]
> ```

Ordinarily, the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against the %-decoded URL-path. However, if the `NoDecode` option has been set then the encoded slash (`%2F`) is not decoded. So the above "should" work (except that the pattern is not anchored, so potentially matches too much).

But note that multiple (decoded) slashes are reduced in the URL-path that is matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. So matching multiple-contiguous slashes here is not possible.

I would instead match against the `THE_REQUEST` server variable, which is as per the original request and always remains %-encoded (if that is how the request has been made). And multiple slashes are preserved. Note that `THE_REQUEST` contains the first line of the HTTP request headers, not just the URL-path.

For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/%2FE [NC]
RewriteRule . /blog [R=301,L]
```

You should *not* use the `<IfModule>` wrapper here.